# SQL Timestamp Where clause 30 mins ago

Tags: sql, mysql, timestamp

How can I see if a time stamp was from >= 30 mins ago? Sorry if I am not descriptive enough but idk what else to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NOW()-1800<=$THE_TIME_STAMP
```

the above obviously is wrong, should be

```
unix_timestamp()-1800<=$THE_TIME_STAMP
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where timestamp_field < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -30 MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select
   *
from
   tbl
where
   timestampdiff(minute, tbl.`date_time_field`, now()) >= 30
```

[timestampdiff() @ mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

Answer (score 0):

```
convert(datetime, @ts) >= dateadd(minute, -30, getDate())
```

Replace @ts with your actual timestamp value.